# Using Google Drive API to get Google Sheets from Google Drive and converting in JSON - libraries for authentication or authorization are deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-drive-api, deprecated

I'm using Google Drive API to get an xlsx file from Google Drive and convert in JSON so I can then use values for creating map markers but I have an error saying the Auth libraries are deprecated, I tried to follow the migration guide but is my first experience using Google Drive API and I found it not so clear.

I was able to load and convert an xlsx file locally but when trying to get it from external server I got the CORS error so I found that using Google Drive API will be the good solution to get the file from it.

Error:

```
Uncaught 
Object { error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that are deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information." }​
details: "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that are deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
<prototype>: Object { … }
cb=gapi.loaded_0:123:44
```

Here's my code:

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
    const API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';

    function initClient() {
      gapi.load('client:auth2', {
        callback: function() {
          // Inizializza l'API client
          gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          }).then(function () {
            // Verifica lo stato di autenticazione
            const isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
            if (isSignedIn) {
              // Utente già autenticato, esegui l'azione desiderata
              loadSheetsFile();
            } else {
              // Utente non autenticato, richiedi l'autorizzazione
              gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(function () {
                // Utente autorizzato, esegui l'azione desiderata
                loadSheetsFile();
              });
            }
          });
        },
        onerror: function() {
          // Gestisci errori
          console.log('Errore durante il caricamento dell\'API client.');
        },
        timeout: 10000, // Timeout di 10 secondi
        ontimeout: function() {
          // Gestisci timeout
          console.log('Timeout durante il caricamento dell\'API client.');
        },
      });
    }

    function loadSheetsFile() {
      gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        q: "name='MY_FILE_NAME.xlsx'", // Sostituisci con il nome del tuo file
        spaces: 'drive',
        fields: 'files(id, name)'
      }).then(function (response) {
        const files = response.result.files;
        if (files && files.length > 0) {
          const fileId = files[0].id;
          downloadSheetsFile(fileId);
        } else {
          console.log('File non trovato.');
        }
      });
    }

    function downloadSheetsFile(fileId) {
      gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        fileId: fileId,
        alt: 'media'
      }).then(function (response) {
        const content = response.body;

        // Ora puoi elaborare il file XLSX come desideri
        // Ad esempio, puoi utilizzare xlsx.js per convertirlo in JSON

        const workbook = XLSX.read(content, { type: 'binary' });
        const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
        console.log('Dati JSON:', jsonData);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=initClient"></script>
```

Comment: Which line did your error occur in your showing script?

Comment: i think is the 0:123:44

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `i think is the 0:123:44`, I couldn't understand the error line of your showing script. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the **gapi.client.init** with **google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient**. You find a detailed example if you go to https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis?hl=en#implicit-flow and look at the first example with "The old way" and "The new way" in "Implicit flow examples" you can see everything you need to change to perform the migration.

Comment: I can't get it, i replaced gapi.client.init with:

client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly \
                  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
          callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
          },
        });
but it gove me error, google is not defined

Comment: hi, i hope you change the correct value right? For example in client_id you need use your id CLIENT_ID (and not YOUR_CLIENT_ID) and in scope you need use your scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file (and not calendar that use only for example)